# visual studio cl.exe link .lib files by path

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, cl.exe

Currently I compile and link c++ program like this

```
cl.exe /EHsc main.cpp /link kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib
```

It looks very awkward, I tried this

```
cl.exe /EHsc main.cpp /link /LIBPATH:"D:\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64"
```

It did not work. you have to specify each .lib file individually.

Any solution?

PS:
my sample main.cpp code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    SetCursorPos(1000, 1000);
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***Any solution?*** Your first example is the solution. You need to link to each individual library you use.  Setting the directory to look for libs does not help.

Comment: The linker won't know which libraries to link to unless you specify the libraries to link. So your first example is the solution

Comment: Imagine the library search path includes hundreds of libraries including multiple versions and debug/release versions. Would you really want it to try and figure out what to link? Even if it got it 100% right can you imagine how much time that might add to a build? If it bugs you make a batch file or a makefile so you only need to do it once.

Comment: Even if what you said is true, how do you know which libs should be specified?

Comment: @GaryAllen Experience, documentation, tool defaults, experimentation. If you miss any out you'll get a linker error, then you can look that function up and find out what library it is part of.

Comment: In msdn if you go to the documentation for a header it tells you the library that is needed. Most of the time the defaults are all that are needed but sometimes you have to add additional entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library name must be specified explicitly in the linker.

If you check Linker option-> Marco in Visual Studio, you will find that there is marco $(CoreLibraryDependencies);%(AdditionalDependencies).

And you can do something like this in Developer Powershell for Visual Studio(`the tool can be found in Win->Visual Studio folder`).

```
$CoreLibraryDependencies=@("kernel32.lib","user32.lib","gdi32.lib","winspool.lib","comdlg32.lib","advapi32.lib","shell32.lib","ole32.lib","oleaut32.lib","uuid.lib","odbc32.lib","odbccp32.lib")
```

And

```
 cl.exe /EHsc main.cpp /link $CoreLibraryDependencies /LIBPATH:"D:\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64"
```

Of course, it is also possible to  store all libs in the folder into array
via
powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to find the missing libs location.

If you compile your code with cl.exe or clang.exe, if you have missing libs, it will display errors saying `"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CLSIDFromString"`

Then you use grep to search the "__imp_CLSIDFromString" symbol in all of the libs folders.

For example:

```
grep -o --color -a "__imp_CLSIDFromString" /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/um/x64/*
```